# Xpath: How to get values without a element node

Tags: python-2.7, xpath

I want to extract the values 4, 3 and 0 but don't know how since they do not have an attribute name

```
<div class="ea_default_border" style="width:230px; margin-left:20px;">
<span class="ea_default_label">Catégorie :</span> 
<a href='/index.php?option=com_'>Location</a><br/>
<span class="ea_default_label">Type :</span> 
<a href='/index.php?option=com_'>Maison, Villa, Propriété</a><br/>
<strong>Pièces : </strong>4<br/>
<strong>Chambres : </strong>3<br/>
<strong>SDE/Salle de bains : </strong>0       
</div>
```

I want the desired result to be

4
3
0

and

Pièces : 4

Chambres : 3

SDE/Salle de bains : 0

I have tried several guess that isn't giving the desired result. Thanks in advance for your answers

EDIT: I tried the following xpaths
    //div[@class="ea_default_border"]/br/text()  <== This gets me nothing as the numbers aren't in a tag.
    //div[@class="ea_default_border"]/strong/text()  <=== This gets me the titles only.

Comment: Why don't you post some code to show what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
//*[@class='ea_default_border']/child::text()
```

for your second requirement, try this:

```
concat(//*[@class='ea_default_border']/strong/text(), //*[@class='ea_default_border']/strong/following-sibling::text()[1])
```

Comment: That gets me all the texts in <div class="ea_default_border" style="width:230px; margin-left:20px;">. I want only the specified texts in the strong tag E.g <strong>Chambres : </strong>3<br/> I want only the digit and/or the text + digit (Chambres : 3)

Comment: Strange, but the xpath is supposed to get only the child text(), not the descendants. Will you try the edited answer above?

Comment: Ah, great. it works, but I made some minor tweaks as I am working with scrapy. ('//*[@class="ea_default_border"]/strong/text() | //*[@class="ea_default_border"]/strong/following-sibling::text()[1]').extract()[:2] works for me now. I get the desired result by slicing. Thank you.